# On selection of dropdown, diffrent tables must be displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 10 tables for ten different batches and I put a dropdown list for users to select which batch list they want to see. Once the option is selected, the corresponding batch table will appear.

All others tables are supposed to be hidden but when the page is loaded. Please provide me a sample code for at least 3 table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why 3 tables? Why not 4 tables?

Comment: 4 is also welcome... but i said it for your's convenience.. :P

Comment: So why are we doing this? Where did you get stuck? Did you make an attempt that didn't work, what went wrong with that? It reads like you're setting us an assignment, or expecting us to do (your) work on your behalf. We'll *help*, but only if you've made an actual attempt and can demonstrate your non-working attempts. Or even working attempts that don't quite succeed; just show *some* effort. Please.

Comment: @user3613379 Did any answer helped you?

Comment: Hi Friends, i dn't know why, when i am writing my code then earlier i created a code that is working but i dn't know where i am making mistake... not a single one is working.. sorry to say but i have not a great idea of jquery.. :(

Comment: @user3613379 1 of answers provides pure JavaScript solution. To use jquery you have to include library. Also, do all actions after page load.

Comment: Hi @SharikovVladislav how i may include libraries for below jquery solutions and no i havn't check that solution totally in javascript..

Comment: @user3613379 so try it. [how to include jQuery library on my html page](http://dabrook.org/blog/two-ways-to-include-jquery-in-your-document)

Comment: Hi @SharikovVladislav now i also tested different codes on fiddle and all are working. what is wrong is that when i am writing in notepad it's not including jquery libraries. Please tell me how to include jqueries libraries when i am running it in local computer. I am totally new to this. Also what i can do for you because i am also new to stackoverflw website, means how i may reward you through this website if i get the correct result. Please for sake of my convenience please just type the whole answer which i need to type in notepad. Thanks Sharikov

Answer (score 1):

Use code below.

JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function showForm() {
     var selopt = document.getElementById("ID").value;
      if (selopt ==1) {
           document.getElementByID("f1").style.display = "block";
           document.getElementByID("f2").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementByID("f3").style.display = "none";
         }
     if (selopt==2){
           document.getElementByID("f1").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementByID("f2").style.display = "block";
           document.getElementByID("f3").style.display = "none";

     if (selopt==3){
           document.getElementByID("f1").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementByID("f2").style.display = "none";
           document.getElementByID("f3").style.display = "block";
     }
     </script>
```

HTML would look like this:

```
<form action = "sample.com" method= "post">
  <select id="ID" onchange = "showForm()">
    First drop down
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3"></option>
  </select>

 <div id = "f1" style = "display:none">
   second table
 </div>

  <div id = "f2" style = "display:none">
   third table
 </div>

  <div id = "f3" style = "display:none">
   fourth table
 </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function.

Example:

```
$( ".target" ).toggle();
```

You need to add on change handler for your dropdown list. On change you will toggle table linked with selected element.

Your html will be:

```
<table id='table1'>....</table>
<table id='table3'>....</table>
<table id='table3'>....</table>
//.... etc

<select id='dropdown'>
    <option value='table1'>Show table 1</option>
    <option value='table2'>Show table 2</option>
    <option value='table3'>Show table 3</option>
    //....
</select>
```

And you jQuery will be:

```
$("#dropdown").on('change', function () {
    $("table").each(function() { // hide all tables 
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var tableId = $(":selected", this).val(); // get linked table id
    $("table#"+tableId+"").toggle(); // toggle linked table
});
```

Note, that you have to add `display: none;` property in css for each tables, so they wouldn't be shown on page load and `toggle()` function will work properly.

CSS:

```
table {
    display: none;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NgyfT/20/)

Comment: it's not working.my code looks like this.where i am making mistakes please guide me.
<head>
<style>
table {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");</script>

 
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#dropdown").on('change', function () {
    $("table").each(function() { // hide all tables 
        $(this).hide();
    });
    var tableId = $(":selected", this).val(); // get linked table id
    $("table#"+tableId+"").toggle(); // toggle linked table
});
 
</scrip>

Comment: Update your question with your fide, firstly. Did you watch demo?it is working code. Demo is working.

Comment: Fiddle example working even in android Firefox browser

Comment: @user3613379 + you have an error in your code: `</scrip>` at the end

Comment: Yes it's working means your code.. i also tried one and that is also working. what i am doing that i am writing code in notepad.. do i need any servers like localhost or something like that?? because i am just running the code in notepad, the html part is working but not the jquery code.. :(

Comment: Use Google search, use debug tool for your js to undertand what cause problem. Js must work in browser without server

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option value="-1"> Select</option>
    <option value="one">one</option>
     <option value="two">two</option>
     <option value="three">three</option>
</select>

<table id="one" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        one
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="two" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        two
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="three" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        three
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() != "-1")
    {
    $('table.table').hide();
    $('table#'+$(this).val()).show();
    }
})
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pnsk4/)